# Ubuntu login screen loop and terminal error on environment variable

Tags: login-screen

It is caught up in a login loop,  but I can log into using the terminal but any other command after logging will give me an error message "the command could not be located because '/bin:usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.

```
Sudo: command not found
```

I tried to edit. /profile but same error message.

[image]

Comment: Image is added in the question. Thanks

Comment: Resolved by  


export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"

Answer (score 0):

Add to the end of your `/etc/profile` configuration file:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:$PATH
```

You could also check what is in `/etc/environment` if there's $PATH variable present. And if present and does not include `/usr/bin:/bin`, you could add it instead of adding it to `/etc/profile`.